# rCharts/Highcharts reversedStacks not working in R

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I want to reverse the order of stacking in a column plot using `highcharts` from `rCharts`. I found `yAxis.reversedStacks` in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversedStacks) but did not manage to get it to work within R. Does anyone have an idea?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(rCharts)

myData <- data.table(XAxis = c(0,1,0,1),
                     Value = c(0.6,0.8,0.4,0.55),
                     Type = c("A", "B"))

plot <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
plot$chart(type = "column")

plot$plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))

for (.type in unique(myData$Type)) {
  .currData <- myData %>%
    filter(Type == .type)

#   .productionPlot$series(name = .type, data = .currData$Availability, 
#                          type = "line", yAxis = 1, stack = .type,
#                          marker = list(enabled = FALSE))

  plot$series(name = .type, data = .currData$Value, 
              type = "column")
}

# from the jfiddle of this API page:
# http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversedStacks
#
# yAxis: {
#   reversedStacks: false
# },
# it should work like this:

plot$yAxis(reversedStacks = FALSE)

plot
```

Comment: With your example, I get serie A below serie B. If I do `plot$yAxis(reversedStacks = TRUE)`, I get serie A above serie B.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not. What setup are you using?

I am using R 3.1.3
RStudio 0.98.1103
and rCharts_0.4.2

Comment: R-3.2.0 and rCharts_0.4.5. You probably should upgrade both.

Comment: Ok that was an easy one. It works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the question itself. I only had to update my packages. In `rCharts` version 0.4.2 it did not work. In version 0.4.5, it does.